# Mopidy installed from source not running on Arch Linux

Tags: archlinux, mopidy

Mopidy is (self-proclaimed:) "an extensible music server written in Python." Since it plays music from a variety of sources and could be controlled by a multitude of clients this sounds like a cool way to give the Raspberry Pi a second use as a Music Jukebox.

On Arch Linux I followed the [instructions](https://docs.mopidy.com/en/latest/installation/source/)  to the letter but `mopidy` is not running but throwing this error upon start:

```
ERROR: Mopidy requires Python 2.7, but found 3.4.3.
```

I have both python2.7 and python3 installed and suspect this to be a problem.

---

Mopidy 3.0, as released in December 2019, now requires Python 3.7 or newer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So mopidy wants python2.7. Ok, that's fine with me after all both versions are installed. `/usr/bin/mopidy` however starts with `#!/usr/bin/python` which is typically a symlink to `/usr/bin/python3` if both python2.7 and python3 are installed.

So the first fix is to change `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2` in `/usr/bin/mopidy`.

Try to run `mopidy` again - still not working:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/mopidy", line 7, in <module>
    from mopidy.__main__ import main
ImportError: No module named 'mopidy'.__main__
```

What's wrong now? Turns out the the packages (mopidy, pykka, certifi, setuptools and tornado) are installed to `/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages` by running `pip install -U mopidy` and are therefore not found by python2.7. To fix this it is necessary to not call `pip` but `pip2` as it will install packages to the library path of python2.7 `/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages`. Check this by calling `pip -V` or `pip2 -V` which returns something like `pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages (python 3.4)` and `pip 6.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)` respectively.

So the second issue is to `pip2 install -U mopidy` instead of `pip install -U mopidy`.

(The latter seems pretty obvious given the fact that mopidy runs with python2.7 but is still a little pitfall one could stumble about.)

Now you should have a mopidy jukebox up and running.

Comment: If `/usr/bin/python` was a symlink to `/usr/bin/python3` then it violates the recommendation in [PEP 394](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0394/) at the time, although as Python 2 is nearing its end of life there seems to be some change in the PEP.